# Accessing files directly after asking for directory using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android

I want the user to give me access to videos folder of his choice using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. Then, I want to detect subtitles file based on a video name. For `videosample.mp4` I want to see if `videosample.srt` exists and then load it if it does. How do I detect the availability of the subtitles file(s) and how do I read it? Is it possible to read it using normal `File` class?

Comment: DocementFile.findFile(fileName);

Comment: Or DocumentFile.listFiles() and then search the name in the list.

Comment: You cannot use File class.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you so much for the information. I will research them.